# Data sharing on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datastore

A while ago I found several articles on how to programmatically store data within an iOS app in a way that all users with their devices write data into a central place (within the Apple ecosystem) where I as an admin can fetch it.
Unfortunately I did not save these links and now I can't find them. I tried searching for various different terms and expressions, but no luck.

Anybody here knows what I am talking about and how to do this?

Comment: ICloud - public database